# Why do I keep getting distortions in texture painting via the use of the curve stroke?

Tags: texture-painting

What causes these distortions when I use the curve stroke in texture painting?

[image]

Comment: Maybe your UV face is too stretched?

Comment: What does your geometry underneath the stroke look like?